# wiered behaviour of listview while scrolling

Tags: android, listview

[**IMAGE URL ---> Please click**](http://postimage.org/image/1b6jug0ys/)

[image]

I am creating a `ListView` which has a `TextView` and a `ProgressBar`. The `ProgressBar` is initially in invisible state. I am providing an `ArrayList` to the `BaseAdapter` that contains data for textviews.

When the item of the `ListView` is clicked the `ProgressBar` is enabled, a Http connection is established and `TextView` value is updated with the data from server. I have used an `AsyncTask` for this.

suppose there are 10 items in the list and i am clicking 1,2,3,4 items, in each item the progress bar is displayed and  the textview is updated. but the problem arises when i scroll the listview. progress bar which is earlier displaying at 3 got displayed in any one the item 7,6,8,9(it is no more displayed in 3). it is not specific that the 3 items progressbar behaves wiered it can happen to 1,2,4 progress bar. progress bar is painted any where. what is happening i have no idea

Activity class where `ListView` is initailized:

```
private void onListViewItemSelection()
{
    progressLstVw.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) 
        {

            downloadFile(url, view, position);
            view.postInvalidate(); 
        }
    });
}

public void downloadFile(String url, View view, int position)
{
    ProgressBar itemProgressBar = null;
    TextView titleTxtVw = null;

    itemProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    titleTxtVw = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_txt_TxtVw);

    progressBar = itemProgressBar;
    progressTxtVw = titleTxtVw;

    Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message message)
        {
            switch (message.what)
            {
                case HttpConnection.DID_START: 
                {
                    Log.d("Twitter Icon", "Starting Connection");
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                }
                case HttpConnection.DID_SUCCEED: 
                {
                    int position = message.getData().getInt("ITEM_POSITOIN");

                    listDataAry.get(position).setTxtData(message.getData().getString("RECIEVED_DATA"));
                    listDataAry.get(position).setProgressData(message.getData().getInt("PERCENT_CMPLTD"));

                    progressTxtVw.setText(listDataAry.get(position).getTxtData());
                    progressBar.setProgress(listDataAry.get(position).getProgressData());
                    break;
                }
                case HttpConnection.DID_CLOSED: 
                {
                    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                }
                case HttpConnection.DID_ERROR: 
                {
                    Exception e = (Exception) message.obj;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new HttpConnection(handler, position).get(url);
}
```

**BASE ADAPTER GET VIEW METHOD**

```
public class ListAddapter extends BaseAdapter
```

{
    private Context context = null; 
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    private ArrayList urls = null;

```
public ListAddapter(Context context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ArrayList<ListData> urls)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    this.urls = urls;
}
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    System.out.println("getCount");
    return urls.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) 
{
    System.out.println("getItem");
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) 
{
    System.out.println("getItemId");
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        ViewController viewController = null;

        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent ,false);
        viewController = new ViewController(row);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.viewController = viewController;
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.viewController.setTextData(urls.get(position).getTxtData());
    viewHolder.viewController.setProgressData(urls.get(position).getProgressData());


/*  if(row == null)
    {
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent ,false);
    }
    viewController = new ViewController(row);*/
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder 
{
    ViewController viewController;
}
```

**VIEW CONTROLLER CLASS**

```
public ViewController(View view)
{
    this.view = view;
    intializeUI();
}

private void intializeUI()
{
    txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_txt_TxtVw);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
}

public void setProgressData(int progressData) 
{
    this.progressData = progressData;
    progressBar.setProgress(this.getProgressData());
}

public int getProgressData() 
{
    return progressData;
}

public void setTextData(String textData) 
{
    this.textData = textData;
    txtView.setText(this.getTextData());
}

public String getTextData() 
{
    return textData;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is not very clear. Especially the third paragraph. Would you rephrase that and put some *relevant* code?

Comment: make time delay for completing the AsyncTask then perform any UI action, Before completed asynctask there are probability of getting null values.

Comment: Cant say anything without looking at the code. Atleast should see the adapter.

Comment: write your `getView`from `Adapter`, code will help.
do you call `adapter.notifyDataChanged();` ?

Comment: Also the getPosition (or whatever its called), getItem, etc... Better yet just post your entire Adapter Class please

Comment: at which line does the nullpointerexception occur.

Comment: Hi all i have updated the question can

Answer (score 0):

Just change below code you will get proper response

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    ViewController viewController = null;

    row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent ,false);
    viewController = new ViewController(row);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.viewController = viewController;
    row.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder.viewController.setTextData(urls.get(position).getTxtData());
    viewHolder.viewController.setProgressData(urls.get(position).getProgressData());


/*  if(row == null)
    {
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent ,false);
    }
    viewController = new ViewController(row);*/
    return row;
}
```